# Get the top 5 clusters by markers size inside it - MarkerclusterPlus

Tags: google-maps, markerclusterer

Am using MarkerclusterPlus for clsutering on google maps api. I need to find out the top 5 clusters formed based on the cluster size(marker size).

```
var totalCluster = that.markerCluster.getTotalClusters();
```

Using this i can get the total clusters how can i move from here to get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method **`getClusters()`** of the markerClusterer returns an array containing all clusters.

when you iterate over this array you may access the markers inside the cluster by using the method **`getMarkers()`** of the cluster. The length-property of the returned array gives you the number of markers in the current cluster.

Create an array from these informations , sort it and then use `Array.slice()` on the resulting array to fetch the top n.